# selecting row in a dataframe according to defined values

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have an annual record of temperature. I need to select special row (days) with five rows before them (to take the mean of five days) and then take the mean of the selected groups. here is my data frame and the following code that i applied but didn't work.

```
Day  T.m
1      22  
2      21
3      34
4      28
5      14
6      7 
7      12
8      22
9      11
10     12
11     14
12     3
13     4
14     11
15     16

a <- c(8, 12,14)

apply(DF [c((a-5):a),2], 1, mean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `mapply`

```
mapply(function(x, y) mean(DF[[2]][x:y]), a-5, a)
#[1] 19.500000 12.333333  9.166667
```

---

Or a vectorized approach would be

```
tapply(DF[[2]][rep(a-5 , each = 6) + 0:5], rep(1:3, each = 6), FUN = mean)
#        1         2         3 
#19.500000 12.333333  9.166667
```